# Navbar and unordered list

Tags: php, css, navigation, html-lists, navbar

I have a navbar with sublists. I use this navbar for a CSS navbar at the top of my web page, with links for the main pages and drop-down lists for the pages in the sub-lists. I would like to use the same structure to create a navbar at the side of my page for sublists.

All of my HTML pages have the following line near the top of the `<BODY>` that creates the navbar:

```
<?php include('navbar.php'); ?>
```

CSS styling of this navbar is taken care of elsewhere.

Suppose my `navbar.php` file has the following:

```
<nav id="mainnavbar>
    <ul id="index">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="personal.html">Personal</a>
                <ul id="personal">
                        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Info</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="professional.html">Professional</a>
                <ul id="professional">
                        <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The horizontal navbar at the top of my page would list "Home  |  Personal  |  Professional", and there would be dropdown menus on "Personal" and "Professional". This navbar is easily included on ALL pages for a uniform experience. Not too hard.

If a user actually navigates to one of the main (or "parent") pages (e.g. "Home", "Personal", or "Professional"), however, I want there to be a second, *vertical* navbar on the side of that page with links to that page's "children."

For example, if the user goes to the "Personal" page, there should be a side-navbar with links to "About Me" and "Contact Info". If instead the user navigates to "Professional", that sidebar should instead display links to "Activities" and "Resume". If the user decides to go back to the "Home" page, the sidebar should display "Personal" and "Professional". (Although it would be 100% fine if it also displayed "Home" -- perhaps it would be easier that way?)

While I could hard-code a new `<nav>` for each page, I already have a unordered list structure and would like to make use of it. Any ideas how this could be done, or if there's a better way to do it?

---

Perhaps I would want to dynamically generate (via the magic of PHP) a second instance of `<nav>` that is a sort of partial copy of `<nav id="mainnavbar">`, listed above, but including one of the nested unordered lists, rather than everything. Then I could position and stylize each navbar separately.

(Note that only the Home, Personal and Professional pages should have a sidebar navigation menu because only they have "child" pages. The "child" pages should not have a sub-menu. )

In essence, I should have the following:

For `index.html`, I should have the following dynamically generated based on `navbar.php`:

```
<nav id="subnavbar">
    <ul id="index">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="personal.html">Personal</a> </li
        <li><a href="professional.html">Professional</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For `personal.html`, I should have the following dynamically generated based on `navbar.php`:

```
<nav id="subnavbar">
    <ul id="professional">
        <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For `professional.html`, I should have the following dynamically generated based on `navbar.php`:

```
<nav id="subnavbar">
    <ul id="professional">
        <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For all other pages, there should be no sidebar navigation. (Or perhaps I should have some default navbar as a placeholder??)

I'm not sure if having the same `id` for an unordered list in two different `<nav>` sections would be problematic, however.

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP to determine what page you are on, and print out different HTML for the different pages. I put together the simplest version of what you are asking for. Use the same principle to expand on this. You can use the `$_SERVER` superglobal to find out the current URL.

```
<?php
// See if current URL ends with "personal.html"
$personal = preg_match('/personal\.html$/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>


<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="personal.html">Personal</a>
                <?php if (!$personal) print '<ul>'; ?>
                        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Info</a></li>
                <?php if (!$personal) print '</ul>'; ?>
        </li>
        <li><a href="professional.html">Professional</a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

All I am doing here is removing the `<ul>` tags for the personal page, which will put the two nested `<li>` inline with the rest of the navbar elements. You need to expand on this to fit the design you need.

Comment: Would I do the same, then, for the professional page? 

This seems to include "About Me" and "Contact Info" to the main unordered list unless it's on the personal page. What I'm looking for is more of a second navbar of sub-items in the nav structure.

Comment: You can use the same general idea for the other pages. Instead of removing the `<ul>` you can setup another `if` statement to do something else. Basically come up with how you want the header to look on each page, then use PHP to dynamically change the HTML layout to fit your design.

Comment: Thanks again! (That's a helpful comment for my general PHP knowledge....) 
I'm going to give this a shot tonight and see if I can't get it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get it. I did decide that if I could dynamically create a second `<nav id="subnavbar">`, and populate it with one of the `<ul>`s from the main nav bar, that would be work, and it would let me stylize each navbar separately. (see main post)